# Random InvalidCastException using ToListAsync on subclass objects

Tags: c#, casting, entity-framework-core

## Context

- I am using Entity Framework Core, SQLite and its spellfix1 extension.
- There are two classes: `MetaMovie` and `FuzzyMetaMovie`
- `FuzzyMetaMovie` is a subclass of `MetaMovie`

## Description

At first, I get an `IQueryable<MetaMovie> correspondingMovies` using `db.MetaMovies.Where(...)`. If no result, then I use `db.FuzzyMetaMovies.FromRawSql(...)` that is assigned to the same variable of type `IQueryable<MetaMovie>`. To finish, I call `List<MetaMovie> tempList = await correspondingMovies.ToListAsync();`.

## Issue

The issue is coming from that last line. I am sometimes, rarelly, getting an `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.MetaMovieProxy' to type 'com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.Models.Metas.FuzzyMetaMovie'`.

I, then, tried calling the code with one of those specifically failing. No issue!! Any of the ones failing tried alone aren't creating the issue. So, I mean here it goes exactly through the same code path and the exception is not thrown.

I sincerely have no idea why is this happening. I know, you have no working code here. But, I am not able to circumvent the issue, thus no easy way to reproduce it.

Any idea?

## Edit #1

I wrote a patch solution that does the trick (see my solution below). Though, I will explain how to reproduce it:

#### Context

- Having two classes one is the child of the other: `A` being the parent of `B`.
- The classes share the same table with a Discriminator column.
- `AsNoTracking()` is not used.

#### Steps

- Make a query that loads an object A with Id == 1
- Make another query that loads an object B with Id ==1

#### Underlying reason of the crash

It is caused by EntityFramework that tries to load an entity of type `B` that has already been cached as type `A`. Thus, the downcasting failure from `A` to `B`.

Comment: you said you have two classes, `FuzzyMetaMovie` is a subclass of `MetaMovie`. but the error message shows you have a third one `MetaMovieProxy`. please explain.

Comment: I am using `LazyLoadingProxies` and that's why. Maybe I could use lazy loading but without proxies. Proxies were easier to use.

Comment: ok. so can you try remove `LazyLoadingProxies` and edit the question? just make it simpler but still reproducible.

Comment: I'll try out some options: removing lazy loading OR using lazy loading without proxies. This will take 2-3 days to fully execute. So I'll be back after that.

Comment: I tried a quick thing removing lazy loading and my foreign of `MetaMovie` is not loaded.

Comment: seems your problem only happens in your large, real project. but in stackoverflow you'd better paste minimal reproducible code here.

Comment: @LeiYang I am aware of the minimal reproducible code rule, but sometimes it is not possible to respect it.

Comment: i don't think your issue is that hard to reproduce. just create a new project with similiar inheritance entities, and proxies and assign a list querayable to a  list variable with different generic type.

Comment: @LeiYang I figured out the problem. My raw query may load a `MetaMovie` already cached by a previous request. Using `AsNoTracking` before `ToListAsync()` fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from a previous call that loads at least one of the movies that is fetched by the raw query.

To fix it, I used (so no cache is used):

`List<MetaMovie> tempList = await correspondingMovies.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();`

I opened an issue in GitHub for the efcore project: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27802

Comment: since you already found minimal reproducible steps(as in the github), i suggest you edit your question with the steps. so you may either get ways to solve or other suggestions.

Comment: @LeiYang I added what you suggested.

Comment: upvoted the question.